# Implementing While and Do While loops in NIOS II Assembly

Tags: assembly, while-loop, do-while, nios

I know this may be a long shot, but I am fairly new to writing code in NIOS II Assembly Language, and I am trying to implement a while loop and a do while loop, but I am coming up short. Below is some code that should work in a hypothetical situation, but I am not sure if it is correct.

I know that if we were using an if statement, we could say, for example, if the

> register rA > rB

then {some body for loop} and the syntax would be

> bgt rA, rB, label

so would it just be then

> label, rA, rB

Or am I like way off? 
Please be as descriptive as possible when answering this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're right: You should use branching statements to go to labels in your assembly code. You can find very detailed instruction if you look in [Altera's documentation](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii51017.pdf).